# PlainTextEdit, How can i print differ font style and font size text at run time?

Tags: c++, qt

I am working on a Qt project where I used QPlainTextEdit to print received data from Machines at run time. Everything is working fine but I want to update some type of data in other style ,for example I used in my firmware '<>' with h  for heading.

**Qt side**

```
if(serialArray[0]=='<' && serialArray[1] == 'h' && serialArray[2] == '>')
{
    ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #524141; color:white; font-family:\"Helvetica\"; font-size:20px;");      //20px

    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(serialArray);  

}else
{ 
    ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #524141; color:white; font-family:\"Helvetica\"; font-size:15px;") // 15px

    ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(serialArray);
}
```

printing first heading with 20px, if next data not heading all font size set to 15px because plainTextEdit property changed not text property. how can I do this at run?

heading always print with 20px/with other Styling

normal text print with 15px/with other styling

I also used insertHTML with cursor but not working as I want.

```
void MainWindow::processSerialdata()
{
    serialArray = s_port->readAll();
    if(serialArray[0]=='M' && serialArray[1] == 'C' && serialArray[2] == 'H')
    {
         MCH_DATA.mch               = serialArray.mid(0,3);
         MCH_DATA.Frame_Id          = serialArray.mid(4,4);
         MCH_DATA.Frame_Len         = serialArray.mid(9,4);
         MCH_DATA.Source_Id         = serialArray.mid(14,12);
         MCH_DATA.Dest_Id           = serialArray.mid(27,12);
         MCH_DATA.Func_code         = serialArray.mid(40,1);
         MCH_DATA.UnitID            = serialArray.mid(42,12);
         MCH_DATA.io_status         = serialArray.mid(55,22);
         MCH_DATA.extra             = serialArray.mid(77,3);
         MCH_DATA.adc_sensor_values = serialArray.mid(80,80);
         MCH_DATA.hp_lp_sensors     = serialArray.mid(160,48);
         MCH_DATA.final_status      = serialArray.mid(208,1);
         MCH_DATA.feature_bytes     = serialArray.mid(209,30);
         MCH_DATA.crc               = serialArray.mid(239,6);
         MCH_DATA.etx               = serialArray.mid(246,3);
         upDateGUI();
    }
    else{
        if(serialArray[0]=='<' && serialArray[1] == 'h' && serialArray[2] == '>')
        {
            ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #524141; color:white; font-family:\"Helvetica\"; font-size:20px;");
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(serialArray);
        }else
        {
            ui->plainTextEdit->setStyleSheet("background-color: #524141; color:white; font-family:\"Helvetica\"; font-size:15px;");
            ui->plainTextEdit->appendPlainText(serialArray);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

appendHtml() seems to work fine; it allows you to specify how you want the text to look, using any of the standard HTML styling tags.  For example:

```
textEdit->appendHtml("<h3>Header Three</h3>");
textEdit->appendHtml("<h2>Header Two</h2>");
textEdit->appendHtml("<h1>Header One</h1>");
textEdit->appendHtml("<b>Bold</b>");
textEdit->appendHtml("Normal Text");
```

yields this:

[image: screenshot of Qt MainWindow example with QPlainTextEdit]

Comment: Kk thanks for reply i will check for this solution, can i fixed first heading  with html postion:fixed; property?

Comment: Dunno, you'll have to try it and see :)